# Jumping to next highlighted search string in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I followed the tutorial [on this site](http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-search-a-string-inside-uiwebview) to use a search delegate to find highlight a string on the uiwebview. My questions is, how can I make it jump to the first highlighted item and then the next highlighted item.

Thanks.